# Timespan to int reservation Tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime, timespan

HI im trying to create a simple reservation form in visual studio that takes an arrival date and departure date, gets the duration and works out the cost of stay by multipling duration by £115 heres my code (the error pops up on line that begins "int nights = dateDiff" and says "Timespan cannot convert to int) thanks in advance for any help:

```
        String arrival, departure;
        arrival = textBox1.Text;
        departure = textBox2.Text;

        DateTime aDate, dDate;
        aDate = new DateTime();
        aDate = DateTime.ParseExact(arrival, "dd/mm/yyyy", null);
        dDate = new DateTime();
        dDate = DateTime.ParseExact(arrival, "dd/mm/yyyy", null);

        TimeSpan dateDiff;
        dateDiff = dDate.Subtract(aDate);
        int nights = dateDiff;

        textBox3.Text = ("" + nights);
        textBox5.Text = ("£" + (nights * 115));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
int nights = (int) dateDiff.TotalDays;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx). It might be helpful ro round (i.e. `(int) Math.Round(dateDiff.TotalDays)` - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx).

Comment: hi thanks for the reply that has sorted despite my numpty moment of setting the aDate and dDate as the same thing (was stumped when it came up with no nights. your a star though cheers